attempted to use private field on non-instance
ERROR  TypeError: attempted to use private field on non-instance, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I try to disable Hermes engine but it is not getting disable
